# How do I count the number of occurances of a value in Influx? (GROUP BY?)

Tags: influxdb

I have a bunch of data in InfluxDB about "articles", and each `article` has a `domain` value associated with it.

I was hoping to display the number of articles, by domain. I might be wrong, but I feel like what I want in SQL is this:

```
select domain, count(*) from articles group by domain;
```

However, this gives me this error:

```
ERR: mixing aggregate and non-aggregate queries is not supported
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your `domain` is a field and not a tag. You can only group by a tag (and time intervals).
If your `domain` was a tag there would be no problem with the query. Although selecting the tag could be redundant since it is already included in the results as the group identifier.

I think Jan Garaj's comment is somewhat inaccurate.

I don't know why you don't get an error that you can't group by `domain` if it is in fact a field. But perhaps the query parser is just first complaining about you having a field that is in fact not being aggregated in any way when it should be.

EDIT: but to address your question, the way you approach it is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use correct [InfluxDB syntax for GROUP BY](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#group-by-tags) (tag is not included in the SELECT  clause):

```
select count(*) from articles group by domain;
```